# How to Convert this Function to Recursive Function

Tags: javascript, typescript, algorithm, recursion, data-structures

I'm trying to convert a JSON into an array of objects.

So far I have this working code where params `data` is the JSON. It could be deeply nested, provided a `properties` key exists.

Therefore in the code below if a `properties` key exists, loop over it and build an array of objects.

**What would be a good way to convert this to a recursive function. So far my feeble attempts have been very lack luster.**

```
const rec = (data: Object) => {
  let obj1;
  for (const k in data) {
    obj1 = this.buildPropertyObj(data, k);
    if (data[k].properties) {
      let obj2;
      obj1.items = [];
      for (const j in data[k].properties) {
        obj2 = this.buildPropertyObj(data[k].properties, j);
        if (data[k].properties[j].properties) {
          obj2.items = [];
          for (const i in data[k].properties[j].properties) {
            obj2.items.push(this.buildPropertyObj(data[k].properties[j].properties, i));
          }
        }
        obj1.items.push(obj2)
      }
    }
  }
  items.push(obj1);
}
```

```
buildPropertyObj(item: string, key: string): ItemsInterface {
  return {
    id: key,
    title: item[key].title,
    description: item[key].description
  };
}
```

For example, I wrote this recursive function that makes an exact copy of the JSON into the array of objects, but it doesn't keep the nesting, it's just a flat array. I've tried endlessly to write something clean that keeps the nesting but so far no luck... :(

```
buildForm(): JsonFormInterface {
  const listItems: any = [];
  const recursiveBuild = (items: any, listItems: Array<any>): void => {
    for (const key in items) {
      listItems.push(this.buildPropertyObj(items, key));
      recursiveBuild(items[key].properties, listItems);
    }
  };
  recursiveBuild(this.formSchema.properties, listItems);

  return { title: this.formSchema.title, items: listItems };
}
```

The JSON:

```
{
  "group_container1": {
    "type": "object",
    "title": "Container 1 Group",
    "description": "Awesome description here.",
    "properties": {
      "group_1": {
        "type": "object",
        "title": "Container 1 Group 1",
        "description": "Awesome description here.",
        "properties": {
          "C_1_G_1_Item_1": {
            "title": "Container 1 Group 1 Item 1",
            "description": "This is a select box",
            "type": "string",
            "enum": ["Option 1a", "Option 2b"]
          },
          "C_1_G_1_Item_2": {
            "title": "Container 1 Group 1 Item 2",
            "description": "This is a select box",
            "type": "string",
            "enum": []
          },
          "C_1_G_1_Item_3": {
            "title": "Container 1 Group 1 Item 3",
            "description": "This is a select box",
            "type": "string",
            "enum": [],
            "properties": {
              "boom": {
                "title": "Boom !",
                "description": "This is a select box",
                "type": "string",
                "properties": {
                  "bam": {
                    "title": "Bam !",
                    "description": "This is a select box",
                    "type": "string"
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The desired result:

```
{
  "title": "Container 1 Group",
  "description": "Awesome description here.",
  "items": [
    {
      "id": "group_1",
      "title": "Container 1 Group 1",
      "description": "Awesome description here.",
      "items": [
        {
          "id": "C_1_G_1_Item_1",
          "title": "Container 1 Group 1 Item 1",
          "description": "This is a select box",
        },
        {
          "id": "C_1_G_1_Item_2",
          "title": "Container 1 Group 1 Item 2",
          "description": "This is a select box",
        },
        {
          "id": "C_1_G_1_Item_3",
          "title": "Container 1 Group 1 Item 3",
          "description": "This is a select box",
          "items": [
            {
              "id": "boom",
              "title": "Boom !",
              "description": "This is a select box",
              "items": [
                {
                  "id": "bam",
                  "title": "Bam !",
                  "description": "This is a select box",
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Can you share an example of input and expected output?

Comment: do you have a small set of data and the wanted result of it?

Comment: I've added some sample data and end result, thanks for your time.

Comment: The `recursiveBuild` function should create the output object/array itself, not append the data to the same toplevel one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In plain Javascript, you could take a recursive approach by looking at key and values from the object and map nested `properties`.

```js
const
    convert = object => Object
        .values(object)
        .map(({ title, description, properties }) => ({
            title,
            description,
            ...(properties
                ? { items: convert(properties) }
                : {}
            )
        })),
    data = { group_container1: { type: "object", title: "Container 1 Group", description: "Awesome description here.", properties: { group_1: { type: "object", title: "Container 1 Group 1", description: "Awesome description here.", properties: { C_1_G_1_Item_1: { title: "Container 1 Group 1 Item 1", description: "This is a select box", type: "string", enum: ["Option 1a", "Option 2b"] }, C_1_G_1_Item_2: { title: "Container 1 Group 1 Item 2", description: "This is a select box", type: "string", enum: [] }, C_1_G_1_Item_3: { title: "Container 1 Group 1 Item 3", description: "This is a select box", type: "string", enum: [], properties: { boom: { title: "Boom !", description: "This is a select box", type: "string", properties: { bam: { title: "Bam !", description: "This is a select box", type: "string" } } } } } } } } } },
    result = convert(data);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Thank you, having a bit of trouble understanding with the indending. Also I'm getting a type error on `{ description, properties }` - `Property 'description' does not exist on type '{}'`  and there might be an extra comma or am I looking at it wrong ?

Comment: which comma are you refereing to?

Comment: this separates variables.

Comment: Awesome it seems to work, took me a while to understand with the indenting.

Comment: If you have several other properties to add, aside from **title, description, properties**, maybe 10, what would be a clean way to add these in ? Just create a variable beforehand and pass that in?

Comment: you could take a function for it to get destructured variables and a new object from it. or take athe unwanted out and take the rest [Rest in Object Destructuring `...`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Rest_in_Object_Destructuring).

Answer (score 0):

Taking **Nina Scholz's** wonderfully correct answer and adjusting it a bit so that it includes the `key` value to create `id` property. Also add indenting and TypeScript types.

```
const recursiveBuild = (data: any): Array<ItemsInterface> => {
  return Object
    .entries(data)
    .map(([key, { properties }]: any, index, item) => {
      const propObj = this.buildPropertyObj(item[index][1], key);
      return {
          ... propObj,
          ...(properties ? { items: recursiveBuild(properties) } : {} )
        };
    });
}
```

```
buildPropertyObj(item: any, key: string): ItemsInterface {
  return {
    id: key,
    title: item.title,
    description: item.description,
  };
}
```

Thank you all.